# Bom dia, estou com uma pagina de login e preciso fazer com que ao o usuario errar a senha, mantenha o email digitado

Tags: php, javascript, html5

```
                                <input name="usuario" id="usuario" class="input is-large" placeholder="Seu e-mail" autofocus"">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field">
                            <div class="control">
                                <input name="senha" id="senha" class="input is-large" type="password" placeholder="Sua senha">  <span onclick="mostrarSenha()" class="lnr lnr-eye"></span>
                            </div>
                            <div
                                 class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdOG78fAAAAAHo10_G0kAlOja3VRjFUsqtNnX_y">
                             </div>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" name="entrar" onclick="return valida()" class="button-submit">Entrar</button>
                        <script type="text/javascript">
                            function valida(){
                                if (grecaptcha.getResponse() == ""){
                                    alert("Marque o recaptcha");
                                    return false;   
                                }
                            }
                        </script>
```

php

```
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($row == 1){
    if($isActive == 0){
        $_SESSION['usuario_inativo'] = true;
        header('Location: loginpage.php');
        return;
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

caso o form seja do metodo "post" coloque

```
<input name="usuario" value="<?php echo $_POST['usuario'] ?>" id="usuario" class="input is-large" placeholder="Seu e-mail" autofocus"">
```

caso o form seja do metodo "get" coloque

```
<input name="usuario" value="<?php echo $_GET['usuario'] ?> id="usuario" class="input is-large" placeholder="Seu e-mail" autofocus"">
```

e no inicio da pagina coloque `error_reporting(0);` dentro do codigo php

Comment: Note que isso cria uma falha de XSS, especialmente no caso do GET.

Comment: Nesse caso, o que pode ser feito é guardar em cookies ou com localstorage o username, não vejo mais nenhuma alternativa

Comment: No caso de cookies o problema é igual, o problema não é a origem da informação, mas como ela é mostrada. O problema é resolvido se usar `htmlentities`, como: `value=<?= htmlentities($_GET['usuario'], ENT_QUOTES | ENT_HTML5, "UTF-8") ?>`, ou similar (não uso PHP).

Comment: Não sabia sobre isso do "htmlentities" e peço desculpa então e obrigado por me corrigir